# Simple Graphical Animated Canvas For Python on Raspberry Pi Zero

Tags: python, pi-zero, gui

Is there any way to efficiently create an animated canvas with python?

Required

- Ability to efficiently render 2D lines and shapes (lines, arcs, circles, ellipses, etc.)
- Ability to show the canvas fullscreen

Bonus

- In-built support for rendering text

I am aware of libraries such as Tkinter which include a canvas feature. I am wondering if there is a more focussed, performant, or efficient method do accomplish this.

Thank you!

Comment: You can draw shapes and text onto a surface in Pygame. You can also full screen the window in Pygame (both you can find out how to so with a quick Google search)

Comment: There is also the FLTK (through pyFLTK), which should be more performat (it is called "fast" and "light").